# Issue with Japanese/International Characters with IIS7 URL Rewrite

Tags: wordpress, unicode, internationalization, url-rewriting

I have a friend with a Japanese blog, using wordpress, he has the pretty url. Basically domain.com/postname. Well an example of a url might be. "domain.com/テスト". His blog is hosted on an Apache web server.

I am running IIS7 and am trying to get my Japanese blog going like it should, and have "domain.com/テスト" show just that one post when you visit that url. My thinking is it has something to do with url-encoding. I can't find too much information on utf-8 or anything about getting international characters to work in a url.

Any help on this would be great. I am thinking I should change something in the web.config file, but not to sure. I haven't had a lot of experience with IIS7.

Thanks.

Comment: This is a wordpress configuration question so it should be moved to serverfault or superuser.

Comment: I don't believe it is a wordpress configuration problem as I have the default web.config for url rewritting for IIS and it works perfectly, minus the japanese. I can't find much information on url rewriting and international characters in general.

Comment: I did a fast research in google and found out that you found a solution in another community: http://forums.iis.net/p/1162119/1922400.aspx. Don't forget to bring it here also, since other people may benefit from it!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This was pulled off of forum post linked to above.

Try adding the following code at the beginning of the wp-config.php file:

```
if ( isset($_SERVER['UNENCODED_URL']) ) {
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = $_SERVER['UNENCODED_URL'];}
```